# Deleting dynamically managed tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database that contains many tables, some of them created dynamically by the software.  The dynamic tables have a consistent naming scheme:

```
dynamic_1  
dynamic_2  
...
```

However, I don't necessarily know how many of these tables there are.

I'd like to be able to delete all of these dynamic tables without dropping the entire database.  I'd like to be able to do this purely in SQL.  (Stored procedures are ok.)  Is this is even possible?

---

Quick addendum.

The solution from Haim and Alexandre works great, but there's one special case we all missed. What if there are -no- dynamic tables? In that case `@v` will be NULL and we get an error when we try to execute. I added a second variable to handle this case:

```
SET @v = (SELECT CONCAT('drop table ', GROUP_CONCAT(a.table_name)) FROM information_schema.tables a where a.table_schema = DATABASE() AND a.table_name like 'dynamic_%');
SET @y = (SELECT IF (@V IS NOT NULL, @V, 'select 1'));
PREPARE s FROM @y;
EXECUTE s;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can run this query and get all the sql queries that you need to run;

```
select concat( 'drop table ', a.table_name, ';' )
from information_schema.tables a 
where a.table_name like 'dynamic_%';
```

you can insert it to file like

```
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/delete.sql';
```

## update according to alexandre comment

```
SET @v = ( select concat( 'drop table ', group_concat(a.table_name))
    from information_schema.tables a 
    where a.table_name like 'dynamic_%'
    AND a.table_schema = DATABASE()
;);
 PREPARE s FROM @v; 
EXECUTE s;
```

Comment: You should probably add `AND a.table_schema = DATABASE()` to search only the current database

Comment: Wow, that looks great.  (And yes, the a.table_schema is useful.)  Is it possible to assign the result set to a variable and execute it in the same script?

Comment: i think you can do it only in stored procedure with loop

Comment: That's fine.  Could I bother one more type for help with the stored procedure syntax?  Thanks!

Comment: @njudge You can do it like that: `SET @v = (SELECT ...); PREPARE s FROM @v; EXECUTE s;`

Comment: @alexandre - you cant do it if Sub query returns more than 1 row

Comment: @aim Yhea but you can change your query to produce only one statement `SELECT CONCAT('drop table ', GROUP_CONCAT(a.table_name)) FROM information_schema.tables a ...` which produces `DROP TABLE dynamic_1, dynamic_2`