# SQL iterate through tables and drop if not certain name

Tags: php, mysql, sql, drop-table

I want to drop almost all the tables in my database (9000 in total).
Don't ask me why they are so many, too long to explain.

So I have 3 tables that I don't want to drop.

What SQL statement can I use to do this?
I have been google-ing for a while but nothing came up!

So I have something like this in mind (in PHP):

```
foreach($tab as $tableList){
if($tab!='foo'&&$tab!='bar'&&$tab!='foofoobar')
mysql_query('DROP TABLE '.$tab);
}
```

Any ideas? even better if all could be a mysql statement!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT table_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE table_schema = 'db_name'
```

will give you all tables in database 'db_name'.

Don't forget to backup your tables beforing running the `DROP` statements.

You could use PHP to execute the DROP statements or dynamic SQL with something like this:

(copied from this question: [**Deleting-dynamically-managed-tables-in-mysql**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212229/deleting-dynamically-managed-tables-in-mysql) )

```
SET @v = ( SELECT CONCAT( 'DROP TABLE ', GROUP_CONCAT(it.table_name) )
           FROM information_schema.tables it 
           WHERE it.table_name NOT IN ('TableToKeep_1', 'Keep_2', 'Keep_3')
             AND it.table_schema = 'db_name' ;
         ) ;
PREPARE stDropTables FROM @v; 
EXECUTE stDropTables ;
```

Comment: ok so the dynamic sql statement right there is way out of hand for me... now I could use the first statement there for the listing the tables and then use php to drop certain ones?... ok, i'll try and thanks again for your advise!

Comment: @Andrei: Note that you don't have to execute a `DROP tableX ;` for every table. You can also `DROP table1, table2, ..., tableN ;` But I guess running 9000 DROPs in a PHP loop won't be a problem. Even better perhaps, so you catch errors, like a DROP failing for some reason.

Comment: yes, thanks for pointing that out! I am right now editing my php loop for dropping tables. Thanks again! Help appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can drop more then one table at once using comma.

```
     DROP TABLE table_1, table_2, etc;
```

Comment: Andrei, the clause would be not including tables you need to drop :) If anything get a list of all the tables and strip out the tables in question before passing them to DROP TABLE (...)

Comment: Yes, this is exactly how I managed it! Thanks for your comment, this is done now, I have finished with it!

Answer (score 2):

from you PHP code, i think you should be using `OR` not AND...

```
foreach($tab as $tableList){
if($tab!='foo'|| $tab!='bar' || $tab!='3rdtablename')
mysql_query('DROP TABLE '.$tab);
}
```

for obvious reason.

well, if you want to do it within MySQL,

you can, list the all the tables first... using

```
show tables > whateverfile.txt
```

and store in a file... edit the file as needed... i.e. remove names  of tables that should not be deleted and add `DROP TABLE` to the first line of the file, and 
execute it within MysQL... `mysql < whateverfile.txt`....

Comment: thank you for your solution with the files! I will try this! Though, the php code you have given me here is not good, because with the OR operator, both the 'foo' and the 'bar' tables will be deleted - rethink the condition! - anyway, thanks for your solution! Cheers!